How to interpolate for 0 between three values in python?
Say I have three columns
1,2,3 with values -5, 5, 15
I need to find where 0 lies between the columns and make it a new column
Here the answer would be 1.5 (halfway between column 1 and 2)
How to do linear interpolation in python to do this for many rows?
Needs to incorporate all 3 columns, so could get an answer like 2.2
If greater than 3, can extrapolate or otherwise just put 3 or na
Thanks!

What do you do if the three values are -5, 5, -5 … or even 1,1,1?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but linear interpolation only works on 2 points, so how are you expecting it to incorporate 3? Still, you'd get a result like 2.2 if that's where the x-intercept lies between 2 points. Also, is this even interpolation if you're finding the x-intercept? I thought interpolation meant the points are known ahead of time, not calculated.

Please provide an example dataframe and desired output. For tips, check out How to make good reproducible pandas examples

You can use numpy.interp for each row. If the target is outside the bounds, you'll get the closest x value.
Example:
df = pd.DataFrame([[-5, 5, 15], [-5, -2, 6],[1, 2, 3], [-3, -2, -1]],
                  columns=[1,2,3])

df['x_at_0'] = [np.interp(0, xp, df.columns) for xp in df.to_numpy()]

Output:
   1  2   3  x_at_0
0 -5  5  15    1.50
1 -5 -2   6    2.25
2  1  2   3    1.00
3 -3 -2  -1    3.00


It is not very clear from the code above how you want to generalize the code, but here's my solution:
row = [-5, 5, 15]

for idx, val in enumerate(row):

    if idx == len(row) - 1:
        print("No change of sign.")
        break

    if row[idx] < 0 and row[idx + 1] > 0:
        print(f"The change of sign occurs in column {idx+1+.5}.")
        break

# > The change of sign occurs in column 1.5.


You don't use val in the loop, so it'd be better to use a range: for idx in range(len(row)-1). And then instead of idx == len(row) - 1, put an else on the loop: else: print("No change of sign."). (Sidenote: I like to leave a comment else:  # no break so that it's clear.)
